# Auto layout Not working correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

So i'm creating an iPhone app only portrait and so while working on my interface i've made the interface below in the compact, regular view (for all iPhones in portrait) but it doesn't show up correct as shown on the right. What is wrong?

[image]

So I've done Chris Trahey's solution and it looked write in the preview but then then when I run it in the simulator it's all messed up. What's wrong?

[image][image]

Comment: have you specified Equal height and equal width.??

Comment: @Tushar Sharma how would i do that?

Comment: watch this http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/autolayout/equal-width-height

Comment: @TusharSharma just tried that now they're all bunched together

Comment: `iPhone 4"` and `iPhone 5.5"` have different sized screens. You need to decide how the interface will react to iDevices with different sized screens. A square checkerboard pattern will not fit exactly on a `4"` *and* a `5.5"` device. More information is needed about what output is expected for each screen size and if this is a Collection View or a static screen.

Comment: @Apple Geek apply leading traling top with equal width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. For every view, connect a constraint to it's container and choose "equal width" - but then add a multiplier to make it actually half width
2. For the left views, constrain leading to left layout guide
3. for right views, constrain trailing to right layout guide
4. constrain left views' and right views' horizontal spacing to each other
5. same with top/bottom/vertical-spacing as appropriate

Though it is worth noting that you'll have to decide which is more important: That the views are square, or that the views take up equal shares of the vertical space. If you want them to be square, add a constraint to each view, aspect ratio of 1:1. Make this 1000 priority (required). If you want equal shares of the vertical space, you could mirror the horizontal strategy and do "equal height" but add a 4:1 multiplier.

Here is a sample I put together for the top 4. Note the constraints on the left, and how I expressed the "half height" on the right. You should be able to extend that to the rest of them.

[image: Autolayout for proportional subviews]

Comment: I've tried your solution but there's a problem. check updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

I was duplicating your problem and tried to solve it. I did it like this:

1. All left and right views constrain leading and trailing space to superview.
2. Top view constraint top edges and the rest of the views constrain  to view above it.
3. Every view is set to be horizontally in container. This constrain will get edited like this for left views:

   [image: 1]]

and leading for the view on the right side.

4. All view have a fixed height.(view's height / 4)

   Hope this works for you.